# Enter ESC/POS Mode on Thermal Printer

Tags: javascript, sockets, printing, titanium, thermal-printer

We've got a thermal receipt printer that we are trying to print to via RAW.

We're opening the Port 9100 using Javascript sockets, however whenever we write data to the socket it prints out what ever we type.

We're trying to get it into command mode though, for example - to enter commands like

```
ESC%-12345X@PJL
@JPL Job
@JPL STATUS
@JPL EOJ
```

However what ever we type, just prints the words. Even when we try type the ASCI, DEC/Hex versions, for example we swap ESC for ^[ to escape it just prints out ^[.

We've also tried by doing

```
telnet printer_ip 9100
PRINTER COMMANDS
```

but it just prints what we type.

The end goal is to have a HTML Rendered Page, Print To A Local Network Printer (No Wan, Cups, PHP, Java) on Port 9100, purely by javascript sockets. (We're actually using Titanium for IOS, so have access to Titanium.sockets)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and am using a Star TSP100 (version 113) thermal printer. Finally, I found out this is set at a hardware level with dip switches: http://www.starmicronics.com/absolutefm/absolutefm/afmmain.aspx?faqid=351.